# Does the ODE $f'-af=g$ have a solution for all $g\in C^{\infty}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $I$ be an open interval and $C^{\infty}=C^{\infty}(I,\mathbb C)$. Does $f'-af=g$ have a solution for all $g\in C^{\infty}$ and $a\in\mathbb C$? Can we explicitely construct a solution?

Comment: Enormous hint - the LHS is $e^{at}(fe^{-at})'$

Comment: The good ole "method of integrating factors"!

Comment: Introduce $\tilde{f}(t):=f(t)e^{-at}$ and $\tilde{g}(t):=g(t)e^{-at}$. $f'-af=g$ and $\tilde{f}'=\tilde{g}$ are equivalent. $\tilde{f}(t)=\int_a^t\tilde{g}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is a solution of $\tilde{f}'=\tilde{g}$, so $f(t)=\tilde{f}(t)e^{at}$ is a solution of $f'-af=g$.

Comment: Is that what you meant @CalvinKhor?

Comment: @Filippo yup, that's exactly what I meant (in fact you can add the constant of integration and give *all* solutions)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you for the confirmation and thank you for the comment (that we can construct the set of all solutions).

Comment: This speaks in favour of my [alternative proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900308/homogeneous-linear-differential-equation-of-order-n-has-n-dimensional-solution-s) that homogeneous linear differential equation of order n have an n-dimensional solution space :)