# Let $A_1,A_2\in L(V,V)$, $A_i(V)=V$ and $\dim\ker A_i=n_i\in\mathbf{N}$. Is $\dim\ker (A_2A_1)=n_1+n_2$ even if $\dim V=\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space that is not necessarly finite dimensional. Consider two surjective linear operators $A_1,A_2\in L(V,V)$ with finite-dimensional kernel: $A_i(V)=V$ and $\dim\ker A_i=n_i\in\mathbf{N}$. Can it be proven that $\dim\ker (A_2A_1)=n_1+n_2$?

In words: Is the dimension of the kernel of the composition of surjective linear operators with finite dimensional kernels the sum of the dimensions of the kernels?

Looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202710/kernel-of-composition-of-linear-transformations) formula, one might think that the formula $\dim\ker A_2A_1=n_1+_2$ is valid, but I have looked at the answers and they are based on the rank nullity theorem, which I can't use, since $V$ is not finite dimensional.

**Motivation:** I want to prove that the solution space of homogeneous linear differential equations of order $n$ is $n$-dimensional by writing the $n$-th order differential operator as composition of first-order differential order with one-dimensional kernel. Actually, the answer to this question completes my [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900308/solution-space-of-homogeneous-linear-differential-equation-of-order-n-is-n-dimen).

Comment: @Hanno In case that helps: I just noticed that the operators I'm dealing with also commute...

Comment: @Filippo Yes, the statement holds regardless of whether the operators commute. Are you familiar with the notion of a "quotient space"? If so, then the proof can be expressed very conveniently.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Of course, if you could write an answer, that would also be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

The result is true, and it only requires that $A_1$ is surjective, $A_2$ doesn't have to be.

Suppose that $$\ker A_1=\operatorname{span}\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\},\qquad \qquad\!\!\!\! \ker A_2=\operatorname{span}\{b_1,\ldots,b_m\},$$with $\dim \ker A_1=n$, $\dim\ker A_2=m$. Since $A_1$ is surjective, there exist $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ with $A_1x_k=b_k$. The set $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n,x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$ is linearly independent: if
$$\tag1
\sum_j\alpha_j\,a_j+\sum_k\beta_k\,x_k=0,
$$
applying $A_1$ we get $\sum_k\beta_kb_k=0$, which gives $\beta_1=\cdots=\beta_m=0$. And then going back to $(1)$ gives us that $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n=0$.

By construction, $\operatorname{span}\{a_1,\ldots,a_n,x_1,\ldots,x_m\}\subset\ker A_2A_1$. Conversely, if $x\in \ker A_2A_1$, then $A_1x\in\ker A_2$, so there exist $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m$ with
$$
A_1x=\sum_k\beta_k\,b_k=\sum_k\beta_kA_1x_k=A_1\Big(\sum_k\beta_kx_k\Big).
$$
So $x-\sum_k\beta_kx_k\in\ker A_1$, implying that there exist $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ such that
$$
x-\sum_k\beta_kx_k=\sum_j\alpha_ja_j,
$$
and this shows the reverse inclusion. Thus $\dim\ker A_2A_1=n+m$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm very happy to be able to complete my proof :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proof using quotient spaces. We note that the map $[A_1] : V/\ker(A_1) \to V$ induced by $A_1$ is a vector space isomorphism. Thus, $A_2\circ [A_1]:V/\ker(A_1) \to V$ has a kernel with dimension equal to that of $A_2$.

On the other hand, $A_2 \circ [A_1] = [A_2 \circ A_1]$. We note that
$$
\ker([A_2 \circ A_1]) = \ker(A_2 \circ A_1)/\ker(A_1) \implies\\
\dim \ker A_2 = \dim \ker([A_2 \circ A_1]) 
= \dim \ker(A_2 \circ A_1) - \dim \ker(A_1) \implies\\
\dim \ker(A_2 A_1) = \dim \ker A_1 + \dim \ker A_2.
$$
To put it another way, we have proved the result with the following commutative diagram:

[image: commutative diagram]

For those familiar with short exact sequences, this amounts to considering the sequence

### $$
0 \to \ker A_1 \overset{\iota}{\to} \ker A_2A_1 \overset{A_1}{\to} \ker A_2
\overset{A_2}{\to} 0,
$$

where $\iota$ denotes the [inclusion map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map).

Comment: Very nice, thank you :) I am not sure that I understand the diagram: Is $\dfrac{\ker(A_1A_2)}{\ker A_1}=\ker(A_1A_2)/\ker A_1$? If yes, is $\pi\colon\ker(A_1A_2)\to\ker(A_1A_2)/\ker A_1$ defined by $\pi(v)=[v]$?

Comment: Yes, $\frac{U}{V}$ is another way of writing U/V. And yes, $\pi$ is just the usual quotient mapping.

Comment: Thank you, it's great to see two totally different approaches.

Comment: @BenGrossmann (+1) & there's a typo in the summarising short exact sequence: The second occurrence of $\ker A_1$ should read $\ker A_2$.

Comment: @Hanno Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

Here's s solution without too many computations (Martin Argerami's is basically the same). We only need $A_1$ surjective. (or even less, that $\ker(A_2)\subseteq A_1(V)$). We don't actually need finite dimension, and the argument below can be adapted easily.

$$\ker(A_2A_1)=(A_2A_1)^{-1}(0)=A_1^{-1}(A_2^{-1}(0))=A_1^{-1}(\ker(A_2))$$
Choose a basis $\left\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\right\}$ of $\ker(A_2)$. Since $A_1$ is surjective, there are $a_i$ such that $A_1(a_i)=b_i$. Let $W=\operatorname{span}\left\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\right\}$

Clearly, $A_1$ restricts to an isomormorphism from $W$ to $\ker(A_2)$

> The usual argument: indeed, the images of the $a_i$ are linearly independet, so the $a_i$ are linearly independent as well, generate $W$, so they form a basis, and $A_1$ takes this basis of $W$ to the basis $\left\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\right\}$ of $\ker(A_2)$, therefore it is an isomorphism. Phew!

Then $A_1(W)=\ker(A_2)$, by construction, and so $A_1^{-1}(\ker(A_2))=W+\ker(A_1)$. Since $A_1$ is injective on $W$ then the spaces $W$ and $\ker(A_1)$ are independent, i.e., $W\cap\ker(A_1)=\left\{0\right\}$, so the sum above is direct:
$$\ker(A_2A_1)=A_1^{-1}(\ker(A_2))=W\oplus\ker(A_1)$$
and therefore $$\dim(\ker(A_2A_1))=\dim(W)+\dim(\ker(A_1))=\dim(\ker(A_2))+\dim(\ker(A_1)).$$

---

You can also show that $W\cap\ker(A_1)=\left\{0\right\}$ directly: Suppose $x=\sum_i\lambda_i a_i\in W\cap\ker(A_1)$. Then
$$0=A_1(x)=\sum_i\lambda_i A_1(a_i)=\sum_i\lambda_i b_i$$
Since the $b_i$ are linearly independent, all $\lambda_i=0$ and so $x=\sum_i 0a_i=0$.